# How can I search data from a table using a field from the 2 tables below

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

So, maybe my questions is not clear enough... I'll try to show it in example.

I have 3 tables:
models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    activate = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department


class Employee(models.Model):
    noEmployee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, default=10) #
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    activate = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.noEmployee)


class List_of_tasks(models.Model):
    myData = datetime.now()
    formatedDate = myData.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    task = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    responsible = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    start_date = models.DateField('Start date', default=formatedDate)
    finish_date = models.DateField('Finish date', default=formatedDate)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

And a small function in views.py

```
def filter(request):
    qs = List_of_tasks.objects.all()
    task_query = request.GET.get('task_contains')
    department_query = request.GET.get('department_contains')

    print(task_query)
    if department_query is not None:
        dep = Employee.objects.filter(department__department__icontains=department_query)

        for d in dep:
            print('department: ', d.noEmployee, d.name, d.surname)

        for d in dep:
            dep2 = List_of_tasks.objects.filter(responsible__noEmployee__exact=d.noEmployee)
            for d2 in dep2:
                print('Tasks: ', d2.task, d2.responsible)

    if is_valid_queryparam(task_query):
        qs = qs.filter(task__icontains=task_query)

    context = {'queryset': qs,}

    return render(request, 'appl01/export.html', context)
```

Finding TASKS or RESPONSIBLE persons in table **List_of_tasks** is easy but I would like to find
for example all tasks assigned to department... two tables down...

As you can see I created my own method which works as I want but is not very efficient. If there are a lot of records in the tables Employee or List_of_tasks then this search is very slow.

```
...
for d in dep:
    dep2 = List_of_tasks.objects.filter(responsible__noEmployee__exact=d.noEmployee)
    for d2 in dep2:
        print('Tasks: ', d2.task, d2.responsible)
...
```

The questions is:
***How can I do this better?***

Thanks for any sugestions..

Comment: Best suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For find all tasks assigned to a department you can do:

```
tasks = List_of_tasks.objects.select_related('responsible').filter(responsible__department__department__icontains=department_query)

for t in tasks:
     print(t.task, t.responsible.noEmployee, t.responsible.name, t.responsible.surname)
```